Struct Cyclic Dependency in C#
I'm encountering an issue with cyclic dependencies in structs in C#
public struct Index
{
    public uint id;
    public IndexList? parent;
}

public struct IndexList
{
    public Index index;
    public List<Index> indices;

The compiler throws the following errors:

Struct member 'Index.parent' of type 'IndexList?' causes a cycle in the struct layout
Struct member 'IndexList.index' of type 'Index' causes a cycle in the struct layout

I understand the reference and value types in C# and their difference, but it seems I'm missing something when it comes to struct dependencies. With classes there's no issue, but I'm specifically interested in understanding why this cyclic dependency occurs with structs.

Structs are a value type and must have to have a fixed size.  Any struct definition that contains itself makes it impossible for the compiler to determine a fixed allocation length.  Making an element nullable doesn't change this because it's not a pointer and it still has to have space allocated for it.  If you want something to be a pointer, then you have to make it a reference type (i.e., an object/class)

@RBarryYoung Yes, thank you. It was a discovery for me that Nullable<> is a structure, after which I understood everything
